# Как преобразовать значения столбца в значения в интервале от -1 до 1?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Есть фрейм данных со значением столбца `Disp` от 0 до 100.

Как преобразовать значения в интервале от -1 до 1, 0 = 50?

Пример данных ([файл с данными](https://dropmefiles.com/1KHyN)):

```
    Date        Disp
15  20160902    19.96316633
16  20160902    22.94098362
17  20160902    33.07775348
18  20160902    41.38989632
19  20160902    58.51188269
20  20160902    75.61025495
21  20160902    82.37119176
22  20160902    84.99476836
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего же сложного:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# генерация данных для примера
df = pd.DataFrame({'Disp': np.random.rand(100) * 100})
print(df.Disp.min(), df.Disp.max())

# пересчет в другой диапазон
df['Disp1'] = 1 - df['Disp'] / 50
print(df.Disp1.min(), df.Disp1.max())

df
```

Вывод:

```
0.44374503539753585 98.15425602284107
-0.9630851204568214 0.9911250992920493
         Disp   Disp1
0   51.584816   -0.031696
1   60.897385   -0.217948
2   35.293204   0.294136
3   32.849050   0.343019
4   70.642605   -0.412852
... ... ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale

df = pd.read_csv(Path.home() / "Downloads/ppppppp.csv", index_col=0)
df["Disp_scaled"] = minmax_scale(df["Disp"], feature_range=(-1, 1))
```